# Sitecore 9 Update 2 - Azure Database Type and Sizes

Tags: azure, sql-database

We are in process of designing the infrastructure architecture to host sitecore 9 update 2 in azure. This requires us to appropriately size all the databases for  Sitecore 9. Also I can't find any good documentation on whether if any of these DBs needs to be single-database vs. elastic pool.

Core database

Master database

Web database

Reporting database

Pools database

Tasks database

Forms database

Marketing Automation database

Reference data database

Shard map management

Shard 0/1 databases

The site will be multisite and visit's per month will be around 500,000/month.  I had a look at this KB below but I can't figure out which DBs should be in elastic pool.
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/267409

Answer (score 3):

I would put everything in a (single)pool and give web a reserved minimum dtu. With an XP0 we see huge gains from having a shared 200dtu pool. This makes the spikes much easier to handle.